# Amazon SQS with C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have been requested to use **Amazon SQS** in our new system. Our business depends on having some tasks/requests from the clients to our support agents, and once the client submit his task/request, it should be queued in my SQL Server database, and all queued tasks should be assigned to the non-busy agent because the flow says that the agent can process or handle one task/request at the meantime, so, If I have 10 tasks/requests came to my system, all should be queued, then, the system should forward the task to the agent who is free now and once the agent solves the task, he should get the next one if any, otherwise, the system should wait for any agent until finishing his current task to assign a new one, and for sure, there should not be any duplication in tasks/requests handling ... and so on.

What do I need, now?

- Simple reference which can clarify what is Amazon SQS as this is my first time to use queuing service?
- How can I use the same with C# and SQL Server? I have read [this topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/how-to-sqs.html) but I still feel that there is something messing as I am not able to start. I am just aiming at the way which I can process the task in run-time and assign it to an agent, then close it and getting a new one as I explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking us to design a system based on a paragraph of prose is a pretty tall order.
SQS is simply a cloud queue system.  Based on your description, I'm not sure it would make your system any better.

First off, you are already storing everything in your database, so why do you need to store things in the queue as well?   If you want to have queue semantics while storing stuff in your database you could consider SQL Server Service Broker (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx#sqlsvcbr_topic2) which supports queues within SQL.  Alternatively unless your scale is pretty high (100+ tasks/second maybe) you could just query the table for tasks which need to be picked up.

Secondly, it sounds like you might have a workflow around tasks that could extend to more than just a single queue for agents to pick them up.  For example, do you have any follow up on the tasks (emailing clients to ask them how their service was, putting a task on hold until a client gets back to you, etc)?  If so, you might want to look at Simple Workflow Service (https://aws.amazon.com/swf/) or since you are already on Microsoft's stack you can look at Windows Workflow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)

BTW, SQS does not guarantee "only one" delivery by default, so if duplication is a big problem for you then you will either have to do your own deduplication or use FIFO queues (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) which support deduplication, but are limited to 300 transactions/second (aka: roughly 100 messages/second accounting for the standard send -> receive -> delete APIs.  Using batching obviously that number could be much higher, but considering your use case it doesn't sound like you would be able to use batching without a lot of work).